# rubyで衝突しないユニークな文字列を生成するには？

Tags: ruby

ユーザがアップロードしたファイルのファイル名を決定する際、ファイル名が衝突しないように
現在時刻（ミリ秒）からIDを発行するという方法を思いつきました。
色々ためしてみて、下記のコードが完成したのですが、現在時刻の数値を62進数に変換しただけなので「p2dhXa6」や「p2d9Wco」のようにファイルの先頭文字がほぼp2で固定されてしまいます。

このままでも良いのですが、ファイル名で利用出来る文字を使って、衝突しないユニークかつ視覚的にもランダムであり、文字列長がより短いIDを生成する方法はございますでしょうか。

**現状のコード**

```
def uniqid()
  def dec62(num)
    table = [('0'..'9'),('a'..'z'),('A'..'Z')].map{|c| c.to_a }.flatten
    num > 61 ? dec62(num/62)+table[num%62] : table[num%62]
  end
  dec62(Time.now.instance_eval { self.to_i * 1000 + (usec/1000) })
end
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## SecureRandom

SecureRandom を使うのが良いと思います。(`SecureRandom.uuid` だとランダムに生成されたことが分かりやすいので、個人的には好みです。)

```
require "securerandom"

SecureRandom.hex
# => "3366ab379a65448704fa7c7cab4b0843"
SecureRandom.hex(32)
# => "4ab79521bf6712c1737b55f8393816b00996de29bed69257c5f6635bea899f9a"
SecureRandom.uuid
# => "d1d145ae-2e1e-4d5f-8f0b-e962c47624e0"
SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
# => "B7Yj6QUYaYtbM7gflqEbaQ"
SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(8)
# => "8CBbCIhp8hA"
```

URL-safe base64 (RFC 3548) は、英数以外に "-" と "_" (パディングを入れる場合には "=") のみが使われるため、ファイル名としても "safe" です。

## Tempfile

一時ファイルを作るという目的だと、Tempfile も良いでしょう。ただし、ディレクトリは固定されます。(ディレクトリはシステムによって異なります。)

```
require "tempfile"

Tempfile.new("moemoe")
# => #<File:/var/folders/sz/slkk1lv965lcpl8djdlq8qdc0000gn/T/moemoe20150124-19905-m2sbfw>
```

## 連番

また、保存するためにユニークなファイル名を作りたいということであれば、連番で採番していくという方法もあります。たとえば、Ruby on Rails (ActiveRecord) を利用しているなら、モデルの `id` をベースにしてファイル名を作ると良いでしょう。(正確にいえば、環境や操作内容によって連番とならないこともありますが、ユニークであることは保証されます。)

```
class UserFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  FILE_STORE_DIR = Rails.root + "store/user_files"

  def filename
    FILE_STORE_DIR + self.id.to_s
  end
end
```

```
uf = UserFile.create
uf.filename
=> #<Pathname:/User/fate/rails/hoge/store/user_files/1>
```

Comment: RailsのセッションIDも SecureRandom を用いていました。

Comment: uuidはユニークなidが発行されることが完全に保証される(？)ことで有名ですが、ファイル名としては長いのと、ランダム文字列をカットすると衝突確率が上昇しそうなので今回は利用しませんでした。しかし、回答としてはとても参考になりました！

Comment: @hojo 短いという条件を見落としていたので、SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64 について追記しました。あと、おまけで連番の話も入れてあります。

Comment: idをベースに連番で保存するという方法は盲点でした。
単純にそれのみだとDBを初期化した際に、ファイルが上書きされてしまいそうだったので、「id連番＋ランダム文字列を数桁追加」で回避しようと思います。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 8):

ファイル名として衝突しないようにするには、作ってみて衝突したら作りなおすという方法もあります。
以下は Linux での例です。ナノ秒まで指定しているので、衝突することはまずないと思いますが、もし衝突した場合はリトライします。

```
begin
  filename = Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S%N")
  File.open(filename, File::WRONLY|File::CREAT|File::EXCL, 0666)
rescue Errno::EEXIST
  # ファイルが存在してたらリトライ
  retry
end
```

複数サーバーや複数プロセス間で同時に動く場合は、サーバー名やプロセスIDをファイル名に含めれば衝突を回避することができます。

Answer (score 5):

単純にタイムスタンプ整数を逆順にしてみました。

```
def uniqid()
  def dec62(num)
    table = [('0'..'9'),('a'..'z'),('A'..'Z')].map{|c| c.to_a }.flatten
    num > 61 ? dec62(num/62)+table[num%62] : table[num%62]
  end
  dec62(Time.now.instance_eval { self.to_i * 1000 + (usec/1000) }.to_s.reverse.to_i)
end
```

10回実行したらこんな感じでした。

1ZrpQzLz
Vq7GJPP
1rPEN7CV
2gUedtTz
Hn4q3VT
2b61d6Yp
Xxtz0d
13Lw0qU9
2BTlK0lb
1fKRd23T

Comment: 整数を逆順にするなんて思いつきもしませんでした！ありがとうございます。

Comment: ほぼ同時に実行されたときにミリ秒が衝突する可能性や、ロードバランサを利用してWebサーバを増やした場合にはサーバの現在時刻のズレから衝突してしまうなんてこと起きたりするのでしょうか。

Comment: ミリ秒の衝突が気になるのであれば、生成したIDにさらにユーザまたはユーザマシンにユニークな ID を付加するやり方がありますね。参考：[Twitterのsnowflakeについて](http://www.slideshare.net/mobile/moaikids/20130901-snowflake)